# how to insert in html using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have got an html table like that

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>
          1
       </td>
       <td>
           2
       </td>
       <td>
           3
       </td>
       <td>
           4
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

the result will be

1 2 3 4

i want the result to be

1 2

3 4

but in run time using jquery

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can restructure table by putting last 2 cells in new row:

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    $(this).after( $('<tr>').append( $(this).find('td:gt(1)')))
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Fyvwd/

Comment: Thanks for your reply..

that's good in case of 4 cells

but i have random number of cells may be greater than 4

Comment: need more details then. My solution has nothng to do with quantity. What do you mean by `random number of cells`?

Comment: works regardless of how many rows  http://jsfiddle.net/Fyvwd/1/

Comment: this table is filled from database so the number of cells is not static may be 4 or 5 and may be more ... 
so i want it to be displayed in rows and each row is only 2 cells

Comment: why didn't you explain that in question? Wastes people's time when you provide over simplified example and don't fully explain issue

Answer (score 1):

**Using jQuery**

*HTML*

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*jQuery*

```
$("#table1 td:first-child").css("float", "left");
$("#table1 td:nth-child(2)").css("display", "block");
$("#table1 td:nth-child(3)").css("float", "left");
$("#table1 td:nth-child(4)").css("float", "left");
```

**Using CSS**

you can also do this using css without using jquery

*HTML*

```
<table id="table2">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*CSS*

```
#table2 td
{
    float: left;
}
#table2 tr > td:first-child + td
{
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/JpCBp)

Comment: `+1` for showing a CSS way of doing it. With your jQuery though, I'd suggest selecting all `td`'s and floating them left, and then filter the selection to `:odd` and clear left. You'll come to the same solution with less code and it's more useful to the OP because it could be used for 1-4 or 1-999 cells...

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

It works but it's not quite right ))

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td:even").css({"display":"block","float":"left", "clear":"left"});
    $("td:odd").css({"display":"block", "float":"left"});
});
```

Comment: almost, i've edited answer, it works correctly

Comment: What's with the loop? All you're doing is processing `td.length` times more than you need to.

Comment: yes, you're absolutely right, fixed

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: i have an idea but i need to know how to implement it

i want to add </tr><tr> at the end tag of the td

any Ideas how to do that?

Comment: edit your post with full html and js part